# How to update StateFlow without emit to collector?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

The question about [UI layer](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer) and unidirectional data flow (UDF). Let's we have `DetailFragment` with `EditText`:

- When user open existing detail, text filled from `StateFlow<DetailUiState>` by `ViewModel`.
- Now user changing text, `DetailFragment` send new text to `ViewModel` that update UI state and due to `collect` fragment receive updated state.  So fragment call `setText` that triggers to send same text to `ViewModel` again.
- If we haven't update UI State when receive new text, for any configuration changes (screen rotation) fragment receive old text value when re-create.

How to exit from such loop?

```kotlin
data class DetailUiState(
    val text: String
)

class DetailViewModel {

   private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(DetailUiState("first text"))
   val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

   fun onTextChanged(newValue: String) {
       _uiState.value = DetailUiState(newValue)
   }
}

class DetailFragment {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        repeatOnStartedLatest(viewModel.uiState) { // flow.collect shortcut
            binding.editText.setText(it.text)
        }
       
        binding.editText.doAfterTextChanged {
            viewModel.onTextChanged(binding.editText.getTextAsString())
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Would `kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel` be a better fit to your problem instead of `Flow`?

Comment: You should probably have some kind of `updating` flag that you can set before updating the `EditText`, then unset after. Then have your `doAfterTextChanged` function check that flag before doing anything - if an UI state update is happening, don't push it back to the VM as a new user input event (because it's not!)

Answer (score 1):

A better way to deal with this problem is to use the two-way databinding feature which saves the text your typed and avoid feedback loops.

In your ViewModel class have a field such as:

```
val text = MutableStateFlow("First value")
```

In the layout file of the fragment:

```
    <data class=".FragmentBinding">
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.sample.YourViewModel" />
    </data>

    <EditText
        android:text="@={vm.text}" <!-- 2-way text binding -->
        />
```

Now, from the `Fragment` class pass in the ViewModel reference and lifecycle owner:

```
private val vm: YourViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    binding = FragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding.vm = vm
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    return binding.root
}
```